# Rendering OpenStreetMap in OpenLayers 3 with more detail and higher DPI

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 and OpenStreetMap to print maps on paper, and for this I'd need to render the maps with more details and higher DPI than are shown on the screen. I'm using CSS to set the size of `ol.Map`'s `target` in centimeters to the desired size for the printout (`.map { width: 7cm; height: 6.3cm; }`).

By default OpenLayers shows one of my maps like this, which is too low detail for my needs:

[image: Undesirable default output]

By changing the map size with `map.setSize(map.getSize().map(function (x) { return x*2; }));` I'm able to increase the detail closer to what I need:

[image: Desired outcome using a hack]

But the problem with this hack is that when the window is resized, the size is reset and it will look wrong like this:

[image: When the hack doesn't work]

How would I be able to control the OSM zoom level and map DPI independently of the map's size on screen to achieve the desired outcome (the second picture) reliably?

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found is to put the map inside two nested `div`s. The inner one has, for example, `width: 200%; height: 200%`, and the outer one would have `transform: scale(.5) translate(-50%,-50%);`. This would double the resolution the user sees.

This approach changes the pixel zoom level relative to the zoom level on screen. However, it needs to be recalculated and updated whenever the user zooms the map.